# cannot execute binary file using execlp() with command in a string

Tags: c++

Im trying to execute a command in a C++ program which is contained a string and get its output to another string but I think I'm doing something wrong with execl(), here my code:

```
void execAndSend(std::string command){
    int fds[2];
    char buffer[1000];
    int res = pipe(fds);
    if (res < 0) {
        std::cerr << "pipe() error" << std::endl;
        exit(3);
    }

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {             
    close(fds[0]);
    dup2(fds[1], 1); 
        execl("/bin/bash", "-c", command.c_str(), NULL);        

    }
    else if (pid > 0) {    
        close(fds[1]);
        read(fds[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer));       
        std::cout << "Command: '"<< buffer << std::endl;
        wait(NULL);        
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "error in fork()" << std::endl;
        exit(4);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

When I run it, i get things like:
/bin/ls: /bin/ls: cannot execute binary file

I want to be able to use all command options, pipes, redirection, etc. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing an argument to `execl`. The first argument is the program to run, the remaining arguments are the arguments to go into `argv`, but you left out the value of `argv[0]`, which contains the name of the program. So it should be:

```
execl("/bin/bash", "bash", "-c", command.c_str(), NULL);
```

Your call had `argv[0] = "-c"`, so `bash` didn't see `-c` as an option, and treated `command` as the name of a script to run.